# How to simplify this "Clear" Command?

Tags: c#

So this is my code for the RESET button. it's pretty complex and long.

```
 textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
 comboBox1.Text = string.Empty;
 textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
 radioButton1.Checked = false;
 radioButton2.Checked = false;
 checkBox1.Checked = false;
 checkBox2.Checked = false;
 comboBox2.Text = string.Empty;
 textBox3.Text = string.Empty;
 textBox4.Text = string.Empty;
 textBox5.Text = string.Empty;
```

I Was Wondering can i just simplify this command using Looping or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is definitely not *complex*. It is very straightforward; there is no question about what is going on in your code. And, in my opinion, it is not very long. I like it.

That being said, if you have a lot of code that empties out multiple textboxes, you could be write a little method like this one:

```
void ClearTextboxes(params TextBox[] args)
{
    foreach (var textbox in args) textbox.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Then call it with

```
ClearTextboxes(textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5);
```

Or if you plan to do this to every single textbox on the form, you could do something like this:

```
foreach (var textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) textbox.Text = string.Empty;
```

And you could do similar things for checkboxes and radio buttons, e.g.

```
foreach (var checkbox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) checkbox.Checked = false;
```

P.S. If you really want to make your code easier to work with, I would rename those controls with names that are meaningful, e.g. instead of `textBox1` perhaps `UserNameTextBox` (or some other descriptive name). That would be a much bigger improvement than shortening the clear command code.

Comment: Thanks A lot for your help. it works pretty good